# if/if else/else

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm new to C# and have the following problem.

A program to calculate the duty to be paid on a vehicle. The user enters the type of car(there are 3 types), length of licence(6 or 12 months) and emission band (5 types) and the program prints out the cost of the license:

my code works perfectly as long as I choose 6 months licence length.

please help me understand what mistake I've made, thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool check;
        int car, length;
        double rate = 0;
        string band = "";


        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12}", "Diesel Car", "Petrol Car", "Alt. Fuel Car");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12}", "TC 49", "TC 48", "TC 59");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Car Type (TC #): ");
        check = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out car);
        if (check)
        {
            if (car == 49)
            {

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
                    length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (length == 6)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                        band = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (band == "AA")
                        {
                            rate = 44;
                        }
                        else if (band == "A")
                        {
                            rate = 60.5;
                        }
                        else if (band == "B")
                        {
                            rate = 71.5;
                        }
                        else if (band == "C")
                        {
                            rate = 82.5;
                        }
                        else if (band == "D")
                        {
                            rate = 88;
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D

                    }
                    else if (length == 12)
                    {
                        if (band == "AA")
                        {
                            rate = 80;
                        }
                        else if (band == "A")
                        {
                            rate = 110;
                        }
                        else if (band == "B")
                        {
                            rate = 130;
                        }
                        else if (band == "C")
                        {
                            rate = 150;
                        }
                        else if (band == "D")
                        {
                            rate = 160;
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D 
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for length != 6 or 12

            }
            else if (car == 48)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
                length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (length == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 38.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 55;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 66;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 77;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 85.25;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D

                }
                else if (length == 12)
                {
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 70;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 100;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 120;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 140;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 155;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D 
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for length != 6 or 12
            }
            else if (car == 59)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
                length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (length == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 33;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 49.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 60.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 71.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 82.5;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D

                }
                else if (length == 12)
                {
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 60;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 90;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 110;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 130;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 150;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D 
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for length != 6 or 12
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for car number != 48,49 or 59
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for car num != int
        Console.WriteLine(rate);
    }
```

Comment: You could also use `switch` statements.

Comment: I recommend to do a basic programming course. Because your code displays a lack of understanding how to write ... programs. Just an example: To reduce the amount of if/else branches you really should use a 'Dictionary'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem in your provided code:**

You are not getting the user input for `band` when the user chooses `12`

Try:

```
else if (length == 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
    band = Console.ReadLine();
    //etc ...
```

**Improvement:**

Important when writing code (specially in the code you provided) is to worry about readability and see if we don't have to much duplicated code.

As already numerous comments imply, the structure of how you have written the code is far from optimal. `Tuples` are already mentioned an are certainly a good way.

My example demonstrates how you would do this using a `Car class` instead and is another possible solution of improvement.

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Car> CarList;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PopulateCars();

        int car, length;
        decimal rate = 0m;
        Car.CarBand band;

        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12}", "Diesel Car", "Petrol Car", "Alt. Fuel Car");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12}", "TC 49", "TC 48", "TC 59");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Car Type (TC #): ");
        var keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!int.TryParse(keyboardInput, out car))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid car input, try again.");
            keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
        keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!int.TryParse(keyboardInput, out length))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid months input, try again.");
            keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
        keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!Enum.TryParse(keyboardInput, out band))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid band input, try again.");
            keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        var matchedCar = CarList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CarNumber == car && c.Lenght == length && c.Band == band);

        if (matchedCar != null)
            Console.WriteLine("The rate for this car is {0}", matchedCar.Rate);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Car not found");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public class Car
    {
        public int CarNumber { get; set; }
        public int Lenght { get; set; }
        public CarBand Band { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }

        public enum CarBand
        {
            AA,
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D
        }
    }

    public static void PopulateCars()
    {
        CarList = new List<Car>();

        // Cars 48
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.AA, Rate = 38.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.A, Rate = 55m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.B, Rate = 66m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.C, Rate = 77m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.D, Rate = 85.25m });

        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.AA, Rate = 70m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.A, Rate = 100m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.B, Rate = 120m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.C, Rate = 140m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 48, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.D, Rate = 155m });

        //Cars 49
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.AA, Rate = 44m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.A, Rate = 60.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.B, Rate = 71.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.C, Rate = 82.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.D, Rate = 88m });

        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.AA, Rate = 80m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.A, Rate = 110m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.B, Rate = 130m});
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.C, Rate = 150m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 49, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.D, Rate = 160m });           

        // Cars 59
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.AA, Rate = 33m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.A, Rate = 49.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.B, Rate = 60.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.C, Rate = 71.5m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 6, Band = Car.CarBand.D, Rate = 82.5m });

        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.AA, Rate = 60m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.A, Rate = 90m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.B, Rate = 110m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.C, Rate = 130m });
        CarList.Add(new Car { CarNumber = 59, Lenght = 12, Band = Car.CarBand.D, Rate = 150m });        
    }

}
```

Comment: This might solve the immediate problem... but OP might have a fundamental misunderstanding about... programming. It is more than likely that there will be further complications.

Comment: @MrPaulch I just answered the immediate question in specific *"my code works perfectly as long as I choose 6 months licence length"*. There is no need to go into specific details about *how* somebody should program.

Comment: I don't challenge the fact, that your answer solves OPs question. If the OP is using the *wrong* tools to solve a problem, it might be prudent to mention that. As a bonus better tools could be suggested

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problems as concepts in your code, but your problem why is not working is because:

```
if (length == 6)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
    band = Console.ReadLine();
    //..other stuff
}
else if (length == 12)
{
    //here band has his initial value
}
```

So you need to ask about the band outside the `if(length == 6)`

How you can improve your code. Having nested if is really bad practice so you should always thinks to write code without having arrow structure(nested if).

```
public static void Main()
{
    int car = 0;
    int length = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Car Type (TC #): ");

    if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out car))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not valid number");
        return;
    }

     Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
     if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Not valid number");
         return;
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
     string band = Console.ReadLine();

     Dictionary<Tuple<int,int,string>, decimal> carDataDic = GetCarDetails();

     decimal ratio = 0;

     Tuple<int, int, string> checkRatioKey = new Tuple<int, int, string>(car, length, band);

     if(!carDataDic.TryGetValue(checkRatioKey, out ratio))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("No value found for input data");
         return;
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Ratio is: " + ratio);
}

public static Dictionary<Tuple<int,int,string>, decimal> GetCarDetails()
{
     Dictionary<Tuple<int,int,string>, decimal> values= new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int,string>, decimal>();

     //Tuple Items -> Item1=car, Item2=length, Item3= band), value in Dictionary is the rate which you should have
     values.Add(new Tuple<int, int, string>(49, 6, "AA"), 44);
     values.Add(new Tuple<int, int, string>(49, 6, "A"), 60.5);
     //define all of your cases.

     return values;
}
```

`Tuple` has role of a class in which you store your data specific for the car. It is nice to use because you can use it for key in `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

The branches for `length == 12` don't prompt for a value for `band`. You'll need to duplicate that question on those branches as well, or else change your code to remove some of the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't take input of Emission Band in 12 months licence length condition.`bool check;
            int car, length;
            double rate = 0;
            string band = "";

```
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12}", "Diesel Car", "Petrol Car", "Alt. Fuel Car");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12}", "TC 49", "TC 48", "TC 59");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Car Type (TC #): ");
        check = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out car);
        if (check)
        {
            if (car == 49)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
                length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (length == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 44;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 60.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 71.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 82.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 88;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D

                }
                else if (length == 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 80;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 110;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 130;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 150;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 160;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D 
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for length != 6 or 12

            }
            else if (car == 48)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
                length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (length == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 38.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 55;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 66;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 77;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 85.25;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D

                }
                else if (length == 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 70;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 100;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 120;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 140;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 155;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D 
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for length != 6 or 12
            }
            else if (car == 59)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
                length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (length == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 33;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 49.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 60.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 71.5;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 82.5;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D

                }
                else if (length == 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
                    band = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (band == "AA")
                    {
                        rate = 60;
                    }
                    else if (band == "A")
                    {
                        rate = 90;
                    }
                    else if (band == "B")
                    {
                        rate = 110;
                    }
                    else if (band == "C")
                    {
                        rate = 130;
                    }
                    else if (band == "D")
                    {
                        rate = 150;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for band != AA,A,B,C or D 
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for length != 6 or 12
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); // error for car number != 48,49 or 59
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); //error for car num != int
        Console.WriteLine(rate);
        Console.ReadLine();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Better code could look like this:

```
// Dictionary from (car,length,band) to rate
static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, string>, decimal> rates =
  new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, string>, decimal>
  {
    { Tuple.Create(49, 6, "AA"), 44m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 6, "A"), 60.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 6, "B"), 71.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 6, "C"), 82.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 6, "D"), 88m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 12, "AA"), 80m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 12, "A"), 110m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 12, "B"), 130m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 12, "C"), 150m },
    { Tuple.Create(49, 12, "D"), 160m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 6, "AA"), 38.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 6, "A"), 55m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 6, "B"), 66m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 6, "C"), 77m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 6, "D"), 85.25m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 12, "AA"), 70m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 12, "A"), 100m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 12, "B"), 120m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 12, "C"), 140m },
    { Tuple.Create(48, 12, "D"), 155m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 6, "AA"), 33m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 6, "A"), 49.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 6, "B"), 60.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 6, "C"), 71.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 6, "D"), 82.5m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 12, "AA"), 60m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 12, "A"), 90m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 12, "B"), 110m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 12, "C"), 130m },
    { Tuple.Create(59, 12, "D"), 150m },
  };

static void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Diesel Car   Petrol Car   Alt. Fuel Car");
  Console.WriteLine("TC 49        TC 48        TC 59");
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Car Type (TC #): ");
  int car;
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out car))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    return;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Enter Licience length in months(6 or 12)");
  int length;
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    return;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Enter Emission Band (AA, A, B, C, D): ");
  string band = Console.ReadLine();

  var key = Tuple.Create(car, length, band);
  decimal rate;
  if (!rates.TryGetValue(key, out rate)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error finding rate for " + key);
    return;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(rate);
}
```

This is essentially the same mybirthname suggested in his answer.

Remark: In the upcoming C# 7.0 (expected in 2017), there will be an even nicer syntax for tuples, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Use switch keyword into this problem instead if, if else, else